# Delete all folders that have numbers as names

Tags: regex, windows, command-line, scheduled-tasks

I can find a way to use regex with the rmdir command on Windows. I need to delete any folder that has names as follows:

- 0855485700
- 54840287805
- 15749678
- 12569
- 9659432665665

Basically, I need something like **rmdir /s /q %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FolderA\SubFolderB\[0-9]***

**[0-9]*** being a regular expression to match all folders with names starting with numbers.

A little background: folders are created regularly by an application. The folders have random names, but the folder names have something in common: they are always numbers.

I need to schedule a deletion of those folders on Windows, so I'm trying to create a task to run a command every month. But I can't find a way to use a pattern for this. And I can't delete all the folders inside the immediate parent folder. I can only delete the fodlers with numbers as names.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I couldn't find a way to target all folders with names starting with numbers with a single regular expression, I ended up creating a batch file with a ***for*** loop that targets all files starting with 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9.

Here's the content of the file:

`for /d %%i in (%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\DriveFS\0* %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FolderA\SubFolderB\1* %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FolderA\SubFolderB\2* %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FolderA\SubFolderB\3* %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FolderA\SubFolderB\4* %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FolderA\SubFolderB\5* %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FolderA\SubFolderB\6* %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FolderA\SubFolderB\7* %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FolderA\SubFolderB\8* %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\FolderA\SubFolderB\9*) do @rmdir "%%i" /q`

If anyone can think of a better solution let me know.